# How to Configure Zuul Multiple instances of one microservice

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, netflix-zuul

i'm working in a spring cloud project and i have an eruka service, zull proxy and a microservice with the name defects-service (zull proxy and my defects-service are clients for eurka) and all works fine.
in my zull proxy i have the following configuration :

```
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone:  http://localhost:8370/eureka/
  instance:
      hostname: localhost

    zuul:
      prefix: /api
      routes:
        defects-service:
         path: /defects-service/**
         url: http://localhost:8300
```

my issue is now i start two instances of my defects-service on diferents ports 8301 and 8302 (registred successfully in eruka service )  but i don't know how to configure my zull proxy to do a load balancing and start redirect requests to my three instances on ports (8300,8301,8302).
note , zull knows only the instance on http://localhost:8300

can anyone please helpe me to resolve this isuue .

Best regards .

Answer (score 1):

Zuul support load balancing out of the box, instead of giving `url` in your configuration, use `serviceId`:

```
 zuul:
      prefix: /api
      routes:
        defects-service:
         path: /defects-service/**
         serviceId: defects-service
```

Comment: Hello @slimane thanks for your response, i changed my config by adding serviceId but i'm getting the following error when i call my service  "status": 504,
"error": "Gateway Timeout",
"message": "com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: Hystrix Readed time out" there is any other config i should add ?

Comment: can you post more stack trace? please add it to your post

Comment: i'm getting  : com.netflix.zuul.exception.ZuulException: 
 at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.post.SendErrorFilter.findZuulException(SendErrorFilter.java:114) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.0.RC3.jar:2.1.0.RC3]
 at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.post.SendErrorFilter.run(SendErrorFilter.java:76) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-zuul-2.1.0.RC3.jar:2.1.0.RC3]

Comment: this is not enought logs, first suggestion: ribbon.eager-load.enabled = true

Comment: thank you so much @slimane for your reponse, i find the solution and i will post it as a response. Regards

Answer (score 0):

the solution of this problem is by using the following config :

```
zuul:
      prefix: /api
      routes:
        defects-service:
         path: /defects-service/**
         serviceId: defects-service
```

after that if you got any error like Hystrix Readed time out.. just add the following config :

```
hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          thread:
            timeoutInMilliseconds: 11000
ribbon:
  ConnectTimeout: 10000
  ReadTimeout: 10000
```